# How to protect sound tracks on android DCIM folder

Tags: android, hide, media

I have an app that downloads sound tracks upon first usage. On Android those tracks are being stored in the DCIM folder.
I hide the folder and files using .FILENAME but is there a way to block access to those files from out side the app by using a hash or password?

This is the code I use to download the tracks -

```
function getTracks() {
console.log('Good to go');
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = 
encodeURI("https://testalice.000webhostapp.com/ATG/tracks/Recording.m4a");
var fileURL = "///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.ATG/Recording.m4a";

fileTransfer.download(
uri,
fileURL,
function(entry) {
    console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
},
function(error) {
    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
    console.log("download error code" + error.code);
},
false,
{
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
    }
}
);
}
```

tyczj - Where would you store it instead so it will be accessible thorough the app only? I am using phonegap build so I have limited app size. The tracks have to be downloaded upon activating the app.

Comment: Why do you download them there where they are accessible to anyone outside your app? You should be saving them to your app data folder that only your app has access to (unless the phone is rooted)

Answer (score 0):

> As long as you use MODE_PRIVATE for your files on the internal
>   storage, they are never accessible to other apps.

If you don't want your files to be accessible by everyone (public), you should download them into private app storage. For this use outputStream with private mode indicator:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream;
try {
    ...
    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ...
}
```

- If you still have problem implementing this suggestion, post your full code.

Comment: Could you post your full code containing this part?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem. For example, you can encrypt track-files (or only n-bytes in each).

Comment: Can you elaborate or direct me to where can I find solutions?

Comment: It is better to us path /sdcard/Android/data/your.apk.folder. You can download m4a-file and then encrypt it. For example, you can use AES [link](https://howtodoinjava.com/security/java-aes-encryption-example). When your program will need a file, just decrypt it.